# React not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

When changing my id (/movie/:id), i'm re rendering my whole component. Sometimes i have to click 3 or 4 times on my like to have a change and sometimes i have only to click once(but im one component behind).
Here is my code :

```js
import React from "react";
import "../styles/DetailFilm.css"
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
const API_IMAGES = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';


class DetailFilm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                    id: props.movie_id,
            info: {},
            recommandation: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            //fetch api
            this.setState({info: data,recommandation:data_recommandation_spliced })
        }
        fetchData();
        

    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log("RENDERING" + nextProps.movie_id)
        const fetchData = async () => {
            // fetch api

            this.setState({id: nextProps.movie_id,info: data,recommandation:data_recommandation_spliced })
            console.log("Rendered" + nextProps.movie_id)
        }
        fetchData();
    }
    render()  {
        return (
            //css
                    {this.state.recommandation.map((movie) => 
                        <Link to={`/movie/${movie.id}`}>
                            <img src = {API_IMAGES + movie.poster_path} className="image-movie-genre"/>
                        </Link>
                    )}
        )
    }

}
export default DetailFilm;
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Where is the logic that triggers the like action?

Comment: There is like action. I'm switching from a movie page to another one.
The action is at the end <Link><Link/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which wasn't the one i was looking for at first.
I changed from using a Class to a function using useEffect avec id as param.

Answer (score 1):

When adding JSX elements from an array, each one needs a unique `key` property so that React can keep track of necessary changes in the DOM. You need to add keys to your Link elements so that React will know to update them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm confused. Should i just in my Link add like key = {id} ?

Comment: Yes. [The documentation has examples, too.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: Thanks for the doc. I understand now whats its important to have key. Unfortunately, still not working properly :(